# get value of class property (NSMutableArray)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, for-loop, nsmutablearray

I'm new to objective-c and have already released the first version of my app in the App Store but I want to improve my app because in the current version, I can only enter 4 player names.

In my new iOS app, I have a table view that lists all names that a user can enter in another view controller.

When the user presses play, I want to display a UIAlertView with the name of a random person.

at this moment, I would like to display all names in the NSLog, but I can't figure out how to do that. with my current code, the app keeps crashing.

I have a class, Zoep, which is a subclass of NSObject. and has the following properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *playername;
@property BOOL *checked;
```

In the tableview controller, I have the following code to display items in the NSMutableArray and to display all names in NSLog. I think i'm that i'm almost doing it right now:

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {

    NSString *aantal = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)[self.zoepers count]];

    NSLog(@"array count: %@", aantal);


    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        NSLog(@"Naam: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.zoepers indexOfObject:[i]]);
    }
}
```

with the above code, i'm still getting the following error and can't compile:

> Expected identifier

Could someone point me in the right direction? When you have any tips for me, I would also like to know them.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSString` is an object and can be print with `%@` and not `%lu`. Update your code and you're with your name.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    Zoep *player = (Zoep *)[self.zoepers objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"Naam: %@", player. playername);
}
```

Conclusion: You're storing `Zoep` class object into your `zoepers` array, so at the time of accessing `zoepers` you would first make reference of `Zoep` class object and then can access properties of that class.

BTW, `indexOfObject:` takes an object and will return index (position in array).

Answer (score 0):

Change ur code as below..

indexOfObject refers to Object of type id..Actually u are passing int instead of object..

U can get the value of some property of object using (.) like obj.propertyname..

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) 
  {
    Zoep *zoepObj=[self.zoepers objectAtIndex:i];

    NSLog(@"Naam: %@",zoepObj.playename);
 }
```

Hope it helps u..

Comment: Thank you, the error is solved, but the output is not correctly. It outputs 2 numbers instead of names??